# How to read multiple json's in for loop where the path is updated from a list?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, for-loop

I pulled and saved a few requests.get json files via a for loop function and now I want to create another for loop that pulls each json file and converts them into a dataframe. The for loop snippet below isn't complete as I cannot continue testing it with the below syntax error.

How do I alter the last part of the path via a for loop?

Also, is it best when dealing with multiple files to create one huge master loop that goes through the entire process one at a time and then proceeds with the next? Or is it better to break each data cleaning/testing step into it's own for loop?

```
file_list = ["API A", "API B", "API C"]

for file in file_list:
    df = pd.read_json(r'C:\Users\username\'+file)
    print(df)
```

**Error:**

```
File "<ipython-input-72-b9019f051ed3>", line 2
    df = pd.read_json(r'C:\Users\username\'+file_list)
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
df = pd.read_json(r'C:\Users\acicchino001'"\\"+file)
```